# Node JS throwing Errors when trying to create new React JS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, nodes

Just starting to learn React and I stumbled with this issue, I tried clearing the cache and the issue persists, what could be the cause of the issue?

Thank you in advanced.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cvhn.png)

Comment: looks like you don't have permission to write in this drive ! try to run your cmd as administrator and set directory path in environment variable

Comment: @Akhil, already did. Still I can't create the project. I tried cleaning the cache tho by executing this command: `npm cache clean --force` and it does not help. It is working fine in my Mac but not in my Windows 11

Comment: remove the space in the parent dir and check again

Answer (score 0):

Firstly confirm you are typing `npx create-react-app my-app` without any spelling mistakes. I have researched and found people with similar issues had an outdated version of node. Try `npm install -g npm@latest`.